# UI unresponsive during AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-interface

I have a dashboard screen that needs to make about 20 AJAX requests on load, each returning a different statistics. In total, it takes about 10 seconds for all the requests to come back. However during that 10 seconds, the UI is pretty much locked.

I recall reading a JS book by Nick Zakas that described techniques for maintaining UI responsiveness during intensive operations (using timers). I'm wondering if there is a similar technique for dealing with my situation?

**I'm trying to avoid combining the AJAX calls for a number of reasons*

```
$(".report").each(function(){
        var container = $(this)
        var stat = $(this).attr('id')
        var cache = db.getItem(stat)

        if(cache != null && cacheOn)
        {
          container.find(".value").html(cache)
        }
        else
        {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/" + stat,
            cache: false,
            success: function(value){
              container.find(".value").html(value.stat)
                db.setItem(stat, value.stat);
                db.setItem("lastUpdate", new Date().getTime())
            }
          });
        }

    })
```

Comment: Have you set your $.ajaxSettings to *asynchronous*? Then it should work.

Comment: I believe async is default for $.ajax?

Comment: async is default: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I added it, and it's still locking. I think it's a combinatin of outgoing requests, and incoming responses (updating UI with responses) that has it locking. There may not be anything I can do about it...

Comment: @cinqoTimo: Sure aysync is default, but what else would lock the browser?

Comment: It's like getting stuck in an infinite loop (which will also lock the browser). JS only uses one thread, so if you're tying it up with expensive operations - you'll lock it...

Comment: OK, I don't know what his "db" object internall does but his operations don't seem to be that expensive.

Comment: db is just a copy of localStorage (var db = localStorage). It could be container.find(".value").html(value.stat). That's touching the DOM on every iteration, and probably causing a reflow & repaint each time. (Repaint because the existing HTML is an image. I think if it was just text, only a reflow would occur)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to jQuery, you can utilize the `$.Deferred` object to make multiple async calls simultaneously and perform a callback when they all resolve.

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

If each of these callbacks are making modifications to the DOM, you should store the changes in some temporary location (such as in-memory DOM objects) and then append them all at once. DOM manipulation calls are very time consuming.

Comment: +1 for the DOM manipulation tip. Each time I call .html() that's probably causing a reflow (possibly repaint as well)

Comment: Can you elaborate on in-memory DOM objects, or send a link? I did a cursory Google search, and couldn't find anything on it..? Would initializing the containing DIV to Display:none, set HTML, then unhide do the same thing?

Comment: basically you want to build a string or DOM object in code, and then only call the DOM manipulation function (e.g. `append` or `appendTo`) once. http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Comment: Yeah, I've used that technique before. The problem is, there is existing HTML, and I need to insert my values, rather than constructing 100% of the HTML. I can't see a way to prevent touching the DOM each iteration...

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems working heavily with SharePoint web services - you often need to pull data from multiple sources to generate input for a single process.

To solve it I embedded this kind of functionality into my AJAX abstraction library. You can easily define a request which will trigger a set of handlers when complete. However each request can be defined with multiple http calls. Here's the component (and detailed documentation):

[DPAJAX at DepressedPress.com](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_ajax/)

This simple example creates one request with three calls and then passes that information, in the call order, to a single handler:

```
    // The handler function 
function AddUp(Nums) { alert(Nums[1] + Nums[2] + Nums[3]) }; 

    // Create the pool 
myPool = DP_AJAX.createPool(); 

    // Create the request 
myRequest = DP_AJAX.createRequest(AddUp); 

    // Add the calls to the request 
myRequest.addCall("GET", "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm", [5,10]); 
myRequest.addCall("GET", "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm", [4,6]); 
myRequest.addCall("GET", "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm", [7,13]); 

    // Add the request to the pool 
myPool.addRequest(myRequest);
```

Note that unlike many of the other solutions provided this method does not force single threading of the calls being made - each will still run as quickly (or as slowly) as the environment allows but the single handler will only be called when all are complete. It also supports the setting of timeout values and retry attempts if your service is a little flakey.

In your case you could make a single request (or group related requests - for example a quick "most needed" request and a longer-running "nice to have" request) to call all your data and display it all at the same time (or in chunks if multiple requests) when complete.  You can also specifically set the number of background objects/threads to utilize which might help with your performance issues.

I've found it insanely useful (and incredibly simple to understand from a code perspective).  No more chaining, no more counting calls and saving output.  Just "set it and forget it".

Oh - concerning your lockups - are you, by any chance, testing this on a local development platform (running the requests against a server on the same machine as the browser)?  If so it may simply be that the machine itself is working on your requests and not at all indicative of an actual browser issue.